# When UnitTesting a function what is the best practice when you mock functions it usees

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

I have a function X and the function uses functions Y. When i test X should i mock Y to return the value i want or should i let it call the real method and let it calculate the value.

```
fun X_test(){
    Mockito.when(Y).thenReturn("value")
    ...
}
```

OR

```
fun X_test(){
    Mockito.when(Y).thenCallRealMethod()
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing the logic that X produces. Therefore you don't care what Y is actually doing, but instead, want to pass "your values" to make sure that the output of X is correct.

Take this very basic example:

```
fun Y(): Int {
  return System.currentTimeMillis()
}

fun X(): Boolean {
  val time = Y()
  return (time % 2 == 0)
}
```

What you want to test, is that `X()` actually returns `true` if the time is an even millisecond. So you'd mock `Y()` to return "easy" values, like 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. And you'd make sure that when `Y()` returns `1`, `X()` returns `false`. But when `Y()` is mocked to return `2`, `X()` would return `true`.

So to answer your question, you'd use

```
Mockito.when(Y).thenReturn(1)
```

And make sure that `X()` returns `false`